# programmatically retrieve project directory in xcode objective-C project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring

How do I retrieve the project directory of an xcode project targeted for the ipad?
Or if it isn't possible, then how do it retrieve the home directory of the user?

something like:

```
NSString *path = [NSProject getPath];//could be absolute or relative
```

or

```
NSString *homeDir = [NSURL getUserDirectory];
```

Answer (score 0):

The user directory is not publicly writable in iOS.  Where to store files depends on your goal, but it will always be within your app sandbox.  Apple sets out guidelines in their [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW12):

```
<Application_Home>/AppName.app
<Application_Home>/Documents/
<Application_Home>/Library/Preferences    
<Application_Home>/Library/Caches
<Application_Home>/tmp/
```

If you would like to expose files in `/Documents` to other applications, including iTunes on the desktop, then [enable file sharing](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW10).

Comment: hi, thanks for your response. I don't intend to write on the directory, I just want to read the path of the project directory of the user developer's home path, so I could use that information to preprocess something before the project gets compiled

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question.  Perhaps what you're looking for is information on the directory variables accessible from the Run Script build phase?  See here: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeBuildSystem/200-Build_Phases/bs_build_phases.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002690-CJABHEIB